# Why are localhost and 127.0.0.1 links blocked?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, content

As a legitimate use of the link, consider the explanation for the nodejs hello world example:

```
% node example.js
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/
```

To describe what to do next, the natural explanation is "go to `http://127.0.0.1:1337/`", but linking to that url is prohibited.  Any particular reason for the ban?

Comment: No one but you could visit it?

Comment: I am no longer able to reproduce: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367397/361484

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Probably because people kept making the mistake of saying:

> My webpage isn't displaying correctly, it looks like this: [http://localhost/my-broken-page.html](http://example.com/my-broken-page.html)

And then they get a dozen comments telling them that link is useless for everyone except them. There's no reason to actually make a link to that; in the case where you need to talk about it for some reason, you can use `http://localhost/` instead of an actual link