# Adding URLs on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, hyperlinks

I need to insert a link to my comments in stackoverflow.

The domain of the url is a template something like --

```
http:// mydomain:host /etc/
```

The issue is that stackoverflow does not let me proceed if I were to add the above URL in my answers. Also if I try to force the addition by adding `<>` i.e. `<http:// mydomain:host /etc/>` Stack Overflow still does not let me.

How do I add such URLs?

Comment: Just add the URL: http://stackoverflow.com/. You cannot add *private* URLs, like `localhost`, however. What *specific* URLs are you prevented from adding?

Comment: And are you asking about *comments* or *answers*? You use both terms in your question.

Comment: Also see [Why are localhost and 127.0.0.1 links blocked?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192771).

Comment: Last but not least, new users (with less than [10 reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user)) can only post 2 hyperlinks per post, to prevent excessive spamming.

Comment: The URL is a template and not an actual url.

Comment: Then use backticks to quote it, like I used when I edited your question.

Comment: You mean something like `http://mydomain:host/appext/` ? Thanks Martinj, that answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to post sample URLs that are not meant to be actual hyperlinks, then post them with backticks to mark them as 'code-ish':

```
`http://localhost:1234/etc`
```

becomes: `http://localhost:1234/etc`.